# How do I open a second Skype instance with a Batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, skype

I want to launch a 2nd Skype instance from a Batch file. 
I have done that successfully with the run window:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary
```

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do the same from a Batch file. Here is a list of my failed attempts:

1. Nothing happens here. Command window opens and stays open:

   start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe /secondary"
2. Command window opens and closes:

   start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary
3. Error message "Secondary does not exist"

   start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" "/secondary"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how can we do it in linux if user is accessing ubuntu box using thin client?

Comment: Duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1201513/how-to-run-two-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time-in-windows-10/1526646#1526646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the "start" command.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary
```

----- edit *-----*

or

```
start "Some Title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary
```

The title is required.

Comment: Duh! How simple can it be? Thanks, mate. Do you know how to make that command line windows disappear after running the batch file?

Comment: I forgot... `start` requires a title.... /facepalm.... and you're right that you need `start` to fork the process away from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Open notepad and type the following line, save this file as a .bat (for **32 bit** windows)

```
start "Some Title" "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary
```

Open notepad and type the following line, save this file as a .bat (for **64 bit** windows)

```
start "Some Title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary
```